# Ransomware/Virus/Malware - modern protection(s)

Tags: malware, virus, ransomware, protection

Just found this on GitHub:

https://github.com/gnxbr/Fully-Undetectable-Techniques/tree/main/minizinh0-FUD

I can imagine similar ransomware, malware, viruses exist.

AV is useless?

Is only Behavior Analytics the way to go?

I can imagine you can implement several layers of security to catch it (i.e HTTP inspection when malware, ransomware, virus, if ever, calls home etc, this would require a nice database of bad IPs)

What other protections are there against Ransomware, Virus, Malware in Windows Environment mostly?

What would you implement, obtain in a Small to Medium Business? Open Source solutions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

### Anti-Virus never offers 100% protection

[This statistic](https://dataprot.net/statistics/antivirus-statistics/) claims that AV software is able to stop about **25% of all attacks**. That can be seen as a positive thing (25% less stuff I have to worry about) or a negative thing (75% still going through).

Common sense, however, is 99% effective. Not opening e-mail attachments from strangers, downloading shady files from shady sites, etc. reduces the risk of compromise drastically.

#### Behavior Analysis isn't 100% perfect either

There is a set of actions that AV software classifies as "malicious", and a set of actions users would like to do in order to do their job. Unfortunately, these two overlap a little, and so AV software has the task at determining how strict to be.

Too strict, and users will complain that AV software is preventing them from doing their job - which then results in the AV software either being tuned to being less strict, or the AV software being removed entirely.

Too permissive, and malware can disguise itself as a user doing user tasks, as is described in the GitHub repository you linked to.

The idea of Behavior Analysis isn't to offer 100% protection, but to complement matching of known malware. This is already implemented in top-of-the-line AV software. In other words, even with Behavior Analysis, the success rate is only 25%.

#### Protections against Malware

There are many approaches, and they're usually together. Generally, you want to prevent malware from getting to your devices, rather than trying to stop it once it's already there. In order to do that, known infection vectors are either prevented or made more difficult.

One way that malware can infect a machine is through exploiting known vulnerabilities in the software and operating system. The solution for that is centralized patch management, meaning that the OS and software is always kept up-to-date and known vulnerabilities are patched as soon as possible.

Another way for malware to infect a machine is via phishing. Phishing can be countered by awareness campaigns, as well as spam filters. For example, an e-Mail prefixed with `!!! THIS EMAIL ORIGINATES FROM OUTSIDE YOUR ORGANIZATION !!!` is more likely to cause alarm when it's supposedly coming from your CFO on a Friday afternoon.

Of course, there are many other infection vectors, but this should give you an overview.

Answer (score 1):

My PC was infected with ransomware and I lost many files.

My solution to this ransomware problem (and all malware) is to use Deep Freeze ([www.faronics.com](http://www.faronics.com)) to protect all files on drive C: (and any other drive). Deep Freeze redirects all new information written to the hard drive to an allocation table, leaving the original data intact. With a reboot, any unwelcome or unwanted changes are removed from the system, restoring it to its pristine frozen state.

The inconvenience of having to save active files on another drive is no problem.  Deep Freeze allows you to temporarily deactivate (thaw) the program so you can periodically revise data on the protected drives.

I recommend updating any protected drives with new or changed data routinely so all new files are also protected. For example - if you own a business and have important client and financial data - you could add the new or changed files once a day to a protected drive so they can also be restored in case of a ransomware or malware attack

It is unfortunate that malware and ransomware make it necessary to protect your files, but this method works for me.  I have many irreplaceable files that I do not want to lose, so I use this as my selected safety measure.

Comment: I don't understand, how could it work. "Correct" ransomware encrypts the files so that you need to pay for the decryption key. It does not matter, what type of OS addon do you use to make them unchangeable *after* the infection. It might prevent a *future* infection, although the required effort is imho unfeasible.

Comment: peterh - Deep Freeze redirects all information written to the hard drive to an allocation table, leaving the original data intact. With a reboot, any unwelcome or unwanted changes are removed from the system, restoring it to its pristine Frozen state.

Comment: So it is essentially a hard disk snapshotter. Thanks!

Comment: peterh - I also recommend updating any protected drives with any added or revised data routinely so all new files are also protected.  For example - if you own a business and have important client and financial data - you could add the new or revised files once a day to a protected drive so they can be restored in case of a ransomware attack.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't do that. Instead, I have incremental backup, long-long-long back, furthermore I don't use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple solution. Use a Web solution or SaaS program to work with your files in the cloud. Not in local or office network. You can try Documentum, or Sharepoint or Dataprius.

With this, the company computers are simple machines that connects to the service and work with the files, the information is centralized.
I don't say that don't use any antivirus. But if the files are in the cloud... they can't be infected by any ransomware. If the computer is infected, you only have to work in other computer meanwhile the IT team clean it.